# Getting "Type 'Promise<IResourceWeightage>' is not assignable to type 'IResourceWeightage'." error when calling method via service method call?

Tags: angular, promise, angular-promise, angular-services

I have this method in one of the service I am using to get `ResourceWeightage` details:

```
getResourceLevelProgress(learning_node_id: number): Promise<IResourceWeightage> {
return this.getOverallProgressData()
  .then(learning_nodes => learning_nodes.find(node => node.learning_node_id === learning_node_id).resource_weightage);
```

}

following is the method in component where I am accessing this method to get `ResourceWeightage` details:

Declaration:

```
resourceWeightage: IResourceWeightage;
```

Call:

```
this.resourceWeightage = this.progressUpdateService.getResourceLevelProgress(this.learningNodeId);
```

I am getting this error while accessing this variable:

> Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type IResourceWeightage.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `getResourceLevelProgress` is returning a promise.

You can either change the declaration of `resourceWeightage` to:

```
resourceWeightage: Promise<IResourceWeightage>;
```

Or change the call to this:

```
this.progressUpdateService.getResourceLevelProgress(this.learningNodeId).then(rw => this.resourceWeightage = rw);
```

Comment: For first solution approach, I cannot use "Promise<IResourceWeightage>" declaration as resourceWeightage object has properties like "progress" and "difference". If I change it to Promise<IResourceWeightage>, I'll not be able to access the properties.

For second approach, I am not able to access properties of this. resourceWeightage object. I am getting this error for following line:
console.log(this.resourceWeightage.progress);
error: Cannot read property 'progress' of undefined

Comment: Yes, that's the whole `async` nature.. You are calling an async function and have to wait for the response before you can do anything with it